# Mounting lug to junction box

Tags: electrical, junction-box, grounding-and-bonding

I need to bond 10 ga stranded EGC to a metal junction box. I’d like to use something like this [lug](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-14-AWG-to-1-0-AWG-Dual-Rated-Mechanical-Lug-with-2-Conductors-and-1-Hole-Mount-2-Pack-G99012/310741806). The box will be screwed to a floor joist in the crawl space under my house.

Does this lug need to be bolted to the box? Can I put another wood screw through it and the box into the joist?

This box is serving as a fan-out point near the main panel because the main panel is so hard to add circuits to (very inaccessible).

Comment: Yes, you want it securely bolted to the box. Wood movement will loosen a wood screw connection over time. The actual purpose and wisdom of the fan-out is a bit suspect.

Comment: I’ve asked about the fan-out in a prior post and consensus seems to be it’s fine. I can run separate grounds, but it would be easier if I can bond the 10 ga.

Answer (score 5):

**You can only put 2 wires on that lug** which makes it fairly useless for a "fan-out". Some people get the idea to twist a bunch of wires together and stick them in 1 lug port.  Nope!  Can't do it unless the lug is specifically tested/listed for that and it says so in the instructions.  (it takes a particular port design).

[image]
[src](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Square-D-1-in-Ground-Bar-Kit/3364860)

However, instead of that lug, you could get an **accessory ground bar** intended for a subpanel - sold by Eaton, Siemens, Square D etc. Those have **many** ports intended for #14-#8 wire, and some are listed for 2 grounds per port.  They're intended for service panels, but if you put one in a junction box, *I won't tell ;)*

You must use a steel box which is listed/approved for electrical use. Those have a minimum thickness.  The thickness assures that a fine-thread screw with -32 thread pitch or finer will have enough thread engagement to be a good electrical connection.

Almost every metal box (except a few large ones) comes with a hole tapped for a #10-32 NF ground screw. Some are on a bump-out so there's room for the screw behind the box.  You can also drill and tap your own 8-32 NC or 10-32 NF hole. Do not put mounting holes into twist-outs/knockouts.

[image]
[src](https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=steel%204x4%20box)

*Note bump-out in lower right*

Thus you have two options to mount a ground bar to a box:

- You can mount the ground bar any old way you please, including running a wood screw through both bar and box, and then run **a ground wire** from the bar to a ground screw on the box e.g. using the provided hole.
- You can mount the ground bar using 8-32 or 10-32 mounting screw(s) and rely on the threads and clean metal contact between ground bar and box. If you use the existing ground screw hole, that is fine if the ground bar is designed to mount through that hole.

---

By the way, on the "fan-out", that is fine as long as the breaker is appropriate for every wire involved, e.g. if any #14 wire is present breaker must be 15A.  What you can't do is merge two 15A circuits and power them off a 1-pole 30A breaker. That needs to be a 1-pole 15A breaker, which may be limiting.

But it is perfectly legit to supply the fan-out point with a *Multi-Wire Branch Circuit* or MWBC.